# Three.js : How to move an object to a little bit right?

Tags: three.js

I would like your ideas to solve my trouble; I tried to have an object, generated by Three.js libraries, in a little bit right position, so that it would not overlap HTML texts.
(I attached the picture below.)

[image]

This is my JS code. Once I wrote "objBook.position.set(100,100,100)" to see the object in a different position.

```
import * as THREE from "./build/three.module.js"
const section = document.querySelector("section.book")
const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
    75,
    window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
    0.1,
    1000
    );

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ alpha: true});
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
section.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

const ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x222222);
scene.add(ambient);

const light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
light.position.set(0,0,6);
scene.add(light);

const loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
// 順番は持ち手、背骨、天面、底面、表紙、裏表紙
const urls = [
    "./pics/edge.png", "./pics/spine.png",
    "./pics/top.png", "./pics/bottom.png",
    "./pics/front.png", "./pics/back.png"
]

const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 3.5, 5, 0.5 );
const materials = urls.map(url => {
    return new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
        map: loader.load(url)
    })
});
const objBook = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, materials );
scene.add( objBook );


// 動きの量を調節する部分
let currentTimeLine = window.pageYOffset / 3000;
let aimTimeLine = window.pageYOffset / 3000;

camera.position.z = 6;

// 本を出現させ、回転させる部分
function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    currentTimeLine += (aimTimeLine - currentTimeLine) * 0.5;
    const rx = currentTimeLine * -0.5 + 0.5;
    const ry = (currentTimeLine * 0.9 + 0.1) * Math.PI * 2;
    objBook.rotation.set(rx,ry,0);
    renderer.render( scene, camera );  
};
animate();

// 画面スクロールした時に
window.addEventListener("scroll", ()=>{
    aimTimeLine = window.pageYOffset / 1000;
});
```

I would be very grateful to your kind support in advance.

THREE.js objects can be moved to different places.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want

```
const objBook = ..
objBook.position.set(dx,0,0);
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. With "position.set()", it worked well.